# How to remove list multiple brackets while reading csv

Tags: python, string, csv

```
with open("D:\Vocabulary.csv","r") as CSV_file:
csv_reader=csv.reader(CSV_file)
for line in csv_reader:
    print(line)
```

I read a csv file (in the file I just had one column contain all the vocabularies)and print the result which contains multiple brackets like this:

```
["apple"],["school"],["big"],[list]
```

So how can I get

```
["apple","school","big","list"]?
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your input and what you have tried.  Further, consider reading [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Consider: `"[" + str.strip("[").strip("]") + "]"`. If you want it to return a list, then use the `eval()` method.

Comment: Your "result" is not clear, especially since what you show is not a valid Python value. Please show code that shows the exact input. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
my_list = [["apple"],["school"],["big"]]
expected_list = [x for b in my_list for x in b] #list comprehension
print(expected_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `list.extend`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
result = []
with open("D:\Vocabulary.csv","r") as CSV_file:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(CSV_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        result.extend(line)
print( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

put your values in a list so it's easier iterating over them;

```
values = [["apple"],["school"],["big"],["list"]]
new_list = []
for v in values:
  new_list.append(v[0])
print(new_list)
```

Hope this if of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
tupl = ["apple"],["school"],["big"],["list"]

lst = [x[0] for x in tulp]
print(lst)
```

***Output***

```
['apple', 'school', 'big', 'list']
```

Comment: Thanks very much,I'm new to Python,so x[0] here means?

Comment: x is a of type `list` when we make `x[0]` we get first value from `list`

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having **string** which needs to be converted to list. Python  [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) will do it for you.

```
csv = '["apple"],["school"],["big"],["list"]'
output = [x[0] for x in eval(csv)] #['apple', 'school', 'big', 'list']
```

Comment: You can use regex match to fetch the results quickly. Let me know!!